# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' - How do I tell python that the string being returned is a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I get a 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error when I try to fetch a key's value which is in turn the name of a dictionary. How do I tell python that the string being returned is a dictionary?

```
choices = ['Country','State','Town']
chosen = 'Country'
country_color = {'Netherlands':'Red','Sweden':'Brown','Ukraine':'Yellow','China':'Pink','Japan':'Black'}
state_color = { .... }
town_color = { .... }

color_data = {'Country': ['col1','country_color'] ,'State': ['col2','state_color'] ,'Town': ['col3','town_color']}
    .....

color1 = lambda v: country_color.get(v['col1']) # this works
color2 = lambda v: country_color.get(v[color_data.get(chosen)[0]]) # this too works  
color3 = lambda v: color_data.get(chosen)[1].get(v[color_data.get(chosen)[0]]) # but this doesn't work; error - 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

    ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`color_data.get(chosen)[1]` returns `country_color`, a string, as you have figured out.

If you want to access the `country_color` dictionary, why not change the value in `color_data` :)?

```
color_data = {'Country': ['col1', country_color] # Notice how it's not a string anymore
```

Answer (score 0):

If you code it like this:

1. `print("Client Name is : {}".format(function).get())`    ----***Wrong***----
2. you will get this error **'str' object has no attribute 'get'**
3. `print("Client Name is : {}".format(FNEntry.get()))`    ----***FIXED***----

Comment: Hello. This question is 7 years old, and already had an accepted answer. Please only answer unanswered questions, unless your answer adds new information (which it does not here). P.S. please try to actually answer the question - what is FNEntry? It is not relevant to this question.